# Nightmare with Localization under Global Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, app-globalresources

I have two Resources files under `App_GlobalResources`

```
MyApp.resx
MyApp.sv.resx
```

*for those who don't know:* All languages will fallback to `MyApp.resx` **except** the Swedish UICulture will use the `MyApp.sv.resx`

and I have a simple page that shows 3 `<asp:Label>` in witch the `Text` property is called differently like:

```
    <i>using Resource.Write:</i><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
    <hr />

    <i>using HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject:</i><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
    <hr />

    <i>using Text Resources:</i><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
               Text="<%$ Resources:MyApp, btnRemoveMonitoring %>" />

    <p style="margin-top:50px;">
    <i>Current UI Culture:</i><br />
        <asp:Literal ID="litCulture" runat="server" />
    </p>
```

`Label3` is the only one called on Page, the first 2 are set like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Label1.Text = Resources.AdwizaPAR.btnRemoveMonitoring;
        Label2.Text = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("MyApp", "btnRemoveMonitoring").ToString();

        litCulture.Text = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
    }
}
```

if I use the **browser language** all works fine, but I want to override that setting and load the correct translation based on other input, so I need to overwrite the `UICulture` and for that I use:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Culture = "en-US";
    Page.UICulture = "en-US";
}
```

witch is the same as:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cinfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cinfo;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cinfo;
}
```

with all this, what I'm getting is this:

[image]

**In other words** I'm getting the correct localization only if I use `code-behind` to set the correct text, all `inline` localization simply uses the browser language.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nightmare is over ...

`Page_Init` does not change the access to Global Resources, we need to `override` the initialization to the culure

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    //*** make sure to call base class implementation
    base.InitializeCulture();

    //*** pull language preference from profile
    string LanguagePreference = "en-US"; // get from whatever property you want

    //*** set the cultures
    if (LanguagePreference != null)
    {
        this.UICulture = LanguagePreference;
        this.Culture = LanguagePreference;
    }
}
```

Now all works correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to change each page, you can set the culture in Global.asax

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim lang As String = "en-us"
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang)
End Sub
```

Comment: I inherit my pages from a single class... added there, but thanks for the heads up.